# What is wrong with this code to remove wp admin bar from one page

Tags: wp-admin

I'm just trying to turn off the wp admin bar on one page, but this function removes it from every page. What am I missing?

```
<?php 
  if ( !is_page('image-upload') ):
    show_admin_bar(false);
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Try [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-the-admin-bar-in-wordpress-3-3/) tutorial.

Comment: Where are you inserting this code?

Comment: In my functions.php

Comment: Please, [research before asking](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=show_admin_bar), there are plenty of examples. :::: Also, the PHP manual is your friend, the Codex too.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why phpcs is showing the error for the line "[phpcs] Removal of admin bar is prohibited."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the (!) infront of the conditional, you can read about [PHP-operators here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp).

Now you simply say that if not on page "image-upload" remove the admin_bar.. Here is the working code:

```
<?php 
function wpse_80018_hide_admin_bar() {
   // If is on page "image-upload"
   // Remove the admin_bar
   if ( is_page('image-upload') ):
      show_admin_bar(false);
   endif;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_80018_hide_admin_bar');
?>
```

Just an example to understand the conditional:

```
<?php
function wpse_80018_test() {
    // If iam on page "image-upload"
    // Echo honey i'm home!
    // If on another page echo "Working on another page!"
    if ( is_page('image-upload') ) {
       echo "Honey i'm home!";
    } else {
       echo "Working on another page!";
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_80018_test');
?>
```

Comment: That's not working either. It shows on every page, including the 'image-upload' page.

Comment: It's not working because of this: [`[Function_Reference/is_page]This tag must be used BEFORE The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). Encapsule this inside a `wp_head` action hook and it works.

Comment: Ofcourse this need to be in a action. Thanks for pointing that out @brasofilo

Comment: Hey, your welcome! If this worked for you, please accept the answer if you can @Pam

Answer (score 1):

#### Hide Admin Bar for everyone

This one is reasonably simple, to hide the WordPress Admin Bar for everyone, add the following to your theme’s `functions.php` file, the first bit hides the admin bar, the second bit hides the settings:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );

function wp_hide_admin_bar_settings() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-admin-bar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

function wp_hide_admin_bar() {
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 
         'wp_hide_admin_bar_settings' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_hide_admin_bar' , 9 );
```

#### Hide WordPress Admin Bar for specific requests

```
if ( isset($_GET['bar']) && 'no' == $_GET['bar'] )
   add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

This would allow you to hide the WordPress admin bar by going to `example.com/?bar=no`, you can of course change those values.

---

**To hide the WP Admin Bar and the Admin Bar preference** on his/her profile page for a specific user, add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wp_hide_admin_bar_settings() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-admin-bar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

function wp_hide_admin_bar() {
   if ( 2 == get_current_user_id() ) {
      add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
      add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'wp_hide_admin_bar_settings' );
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_hide_admin_bar' , 9 );
```

---

Or you could **do the reverse**, and enable the WordPress Admin Bar just for one user, by disabling it for everyone else:

```
function wp_hide_admin_bar_settings() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-admin-bar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

function wp_hide_admin_bar() {
   if ( 2 != get_current_user_id() ) {
      add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
      add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 
          'wp_hide_admin_bar_settings' );
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_hide_admin_bar' , 9 );
```

Comment: +1 for the nice alternatives. ::: Your Answer is not showing properly, take a look at the [formatting guide](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help). ::: Tip: when you find a nice formated question or answer, click [edit], check the markdown and click `cancel` right after, taking **good care of not** clicking `Save Edits`. ::: Doubt: don't the CSS solution leave a blank space?

Comment: Selva, the formatting was really broken, I've revised it. Please, confirm that it is all ok. When you are editing, there is a preview where you can check how it looks. For blocks of code, simply paste it, select all and use the `{ }` button in the editing toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It should be
`<?php 
  if ( is_page('image-upload') ):
    show_admin_bar(false);
  endif;
?>`

remove '!' from !is_page